# How do i match a jcalendarcombo date with the default Mysql date format

Tags: mysql, jcalendar

Am using a jcalendarcombo on a simple interface where a user can pick a date. when i try to save the date to a Db i get an error like this "com.MySQL.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: 'Tue Jul 16 12:06:25 EAT 2013' for column 'date_dispensed' at row 1" and i know its because of the difference in date formats.

Answer (score 0):

The `JCalendar` Component uses a `Date` or `DateTime` of type `java.util.date`, and to save it in a database, you need to convert it to a `java.sql.date`.

You can do something like this:

```
java.sql.date date = new java.sql.date(jCalendar.getDate().getTime());
```

and save the object date in your `date_dispensed`.